# How to get content of notification onesignal and show it in my android app

Tags: java, android, push-notification, onesignal

How to get content of notification onesignal and show it in my android app
When i received it and click on I want my app open and show notification in TextView

Any one help me please

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to get the content of notification (title & content) in my app

Comment: Yes, Stackoverflow isn't a code feeding website you have to show what you have done so far, we will not do your homework for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow :) As we will not write the code for you, try this site, the official documentation from OneSignal, where you can surely find your answer.

[Here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-native-sdk#section--notificationopenedhandler-)